# Spring Batch writing to XML file escaping strings

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-batch

I am new to Spring and Spring Batch and decided to use it to export a bunch of xml files to a third party that requires xml files from our database. My problem is, I am using StaxEventItemWriter to convert an object to xml, but I get output like the following:

```
<categories>&lt;category&gt;First Aid / Safety / Medical&lt;/category&gt;</categories>
```

When I want

```
<categories><category>First Aid / Safety / Medical</category></categories>
```

My Writer is defined as:

```
@Bean(name="OG-ProductWriter")
ItemWriter<ProductXml> productWriter() {
    StaxEventItemWriter<ProductXml> writer = new StaxEventItemWriter<>();
    writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource(exportDir + "\\product-feed.xml"));
    writer.setRootTagName("products");
    // they require ascii
    writer.setEncoding("ASCII");
    writer.setMarshaller(getMarshaller());

    return writer;
}
```

And Marshaller as:

```
@Bean(name="OG-Unmarshaller")
public Marshaller getMarshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    //these do nothing
    props.put("jaxb.formatted.output", true);
    props.put("com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.CharacterEscapeHandler", new XmlCharacterHandler());
    marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(ProductXml.class);
    //this causes exception
    //marshaller.setJaxbContextProperties(props);

    marshaller.setMarshallerProperties(props);
    return marshaller;
}
```

I was asked to include more information about my configuration. I am not using XML configuration and doing it all through java config. The reader is just a JPA repository reader and the processor takes the JPA object and copies it to the productXml product object. I can include more, but I am not sure what else is relevant to the question Im asking.
The step is defined as

```
@Bean(name="OG-ProductExportStep")
Step ogProductExport() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("ogProductFeed")
            .<Product,ProductXml>chunk(500)
            .reader(productReader())
            .processor(productProcessor())
            .writer(productWriter())
            .build();
}
```

I've tried using CastorMarshaller,XStreamMarshaller but I am maybe just not passing in the correct parameters. I have been pulling my hair out trying to get this to work and searched high and low and just haven't found any solution. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

This is a class that I found that I tried adding as a property, but it didn't do anything:

```
public class XmlCharacterHandler implements CharacterEscapeHandler {
    public void escape(char[] buf, int start, int len, boolean isAttValue,
                   Writer out) throws IOException {
    StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();

    for (int i = start; i < start + len; i++) {
        buffer.write(buf[i]);
    }

    String st = buffer.toString();

    if (!st.contains("CDATA")) {
        st = buffer.toString().replace("&", "&amp;").replace("<", "&lt;")
                .replace(">", "&gt;").replace("'", "&apos;")
                .replace("\"", "&quot;");

    }
    out.write(st);
    System.out.println(st);
}
```

}`

My Object if it helps:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "product")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public @Data class ProductXml {
    @XmlElement(name = "product_id")
    private int product_id;

    //this gives the same escaping problem
    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @XmlElement(name = "sku")
    private String sku;
    // cheated and just made string categories.add("<category>string</category>"). 
    // The < and > get translated to &lt; and &gt; 
    @XmlElement(name = "categories")
    private ArrayList<String> categories
    ....(the rest defined the same)
```

}

Comment: There is a difference between the ProductXml's XML structure and the expected XML format given in the first part of your question "<string><category>First Aid / Safety / Medical</category></string>". Also, details of Spring Batch configuration are also missing in your question. Please add that.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I updated and hopefully cleared it up. I am fairly new to Spring so I was not sure what to include or not.

Comment: I am also seeing the same problem in my Spring Batch setup. For some reason the Marshaller does not seem to understand any of the properties set to it.

Comment: Hi, were you able to resolve this question? I am facing the same issue, let me know.